# RSpec sends emails (not storing in ActionMailer::Base.deliveries) - dont know why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, observer-pattern

Im using rspec and when i run rake spec, the user mailer sends email through smtp and not stores the email in the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries-array (invoked by an user-observer)...

Could you give me a hint why?

```
# Rails version
rails -v
=> Rails 3.0.1

# Ruby version with rvm (rvm version 1.0.16)
ruby -v
=> ruby 1.9.2p7 (2010-09-29 revision 29373) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

# Gemfile
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.1"
```

Config-files:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
end

# spec/spec_helper.rb
...
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
...

# app/models/user_observer.rb
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe User

  def after_create(record)
    puts Rails.env
    # => "test"
    UserMailer.new_user_notification(record).deliver
    puts ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.inspect
    # => []
    # Sends it via smtp!
  end
end
```

Comment: What is you Mailer configuration in your Test environement ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm so dumb... had "ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp" in my setup_mail.rb-initializer... AAARGH....

Comment: I had the same problem and I moved that setting to `config/environments/production.rb` and changed it to `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`. Thanks for posting your answer and saving me some time and debugging; you're definitely not dumb :D

Comment: You know in the world, dump people is everywhere... including me!

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on the solution to this problem a little bit more:

In your config/enviroments/test.rb, by default you should have the line `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`

What this does is tell ActionMailer not to send the email normally, but rather store the sent email in the array `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`. This is helpful for testing because you can tell how many emails have been snt by using the inspect, count, length method on the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.

However, if you set the delivery method to something like `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`, that could be overwriting your previous delivery_method = :test; therefore, your `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` won't be populated.

I had done exactly this while using MailCatcher to view my emails being sent, thus causing my tests to fail, even though I was certain that emails were properly being sent!

So, make sure you're not setting a delivery_method other than :test in your test environment.

As a side note: If you're using Devise, you may want to check the `Devise.mailer.deliveries` array instead.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

and I also had

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Which in effect (I suppose) doesn't send the email and also doesn't stuff it into `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` array either.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible gotcha...do not make the mistake, as I did, of including

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

in config/environment.rb, which I incorrectly believed would be overridden by the more-specific config/environments/test.rb. Deleting the above line  from config/environment.rb fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to `.deliver` method inside my `spec.rb`. It's weird, however, I get a STDOUT msg from Rails (Rails 5) of "Email delivered" even without it, which was quite confusing. Looking at your spec made me realize I forgot it. Thanks!